# How i can make a signup with cloud functions the firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm learning to use the cloud functions and may create user with the method `admin.auth().createUser`, but now i would like make a sign up with account  the google

I tried use `admin.auth().GoogleAuthProvider()` but tells me that propiety `GoogleAuthProvider()`  not exist

Comment: You typically implement signup flows in the client app directly using the Firebase Authentication SDK, not on the backend.

Comment: Cesar, give the live demo a try and look thru the code. It's easy to read/follow https://github.com/hightechtelecom/firebaselink

Answer (score 0):

It's not always possible use admin sdk. For example, I'm working with Google Actions and I've resolved with firebase dependencies (npm i --save firebase).
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=es-419

```
async function createUser(token: string) {
    // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);
    const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```